# Blit Queue Optimization Algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graphics

I'm looking to implement a module that manages a blit queue. There's a single surface, and portions of this surface (bounded by rectangles) are copied to elsewhere within the surface:

```
add_blt(rect src, point dst);
```

There can be any number of operations posted, in order, to the queue. Eventually the user of the queue will stop posting blits, and ask for an optimal set of operations to actually perform on the surface. The task of the module is to ensure that no pixel is copied unnecessarily.

This gets tricky because of overlaps of course. A blit could re-blit a previously copied pixel. Ideally blit operations would be subdivided in the optimization phase in such a way that every block goes to its final place with a single operation.

It's tricky but not impossible to put this together. I'm just trying to not reinvent the wheel.

I looked around on the 'net, and the only thing I found was the [SDL_BlitPool Library](http://members2.jcom.home.ne.jp/shirowmiura/BlitPool/index_en.html) which assumes that the source surface differs from the destination. It also does a lot of grunt work, seemingly unnecessarily: regions and similar building blocks are a given. I'm looking for something higher-level. Of course, I'm not going to look a gift horse in the mouth, and I also don't mind doing actual work... If someone can come forward with a basic idea that makes this problem seem less complex than it does right now, that'd be awesome too.

EDIT:

Thinking about aaronasterling's answer... could this work?

- Implement customized region handler code that can maintain metadata for every rectangle it contains. When the region handler splits up a rectangle, it will automatically associate the metadata of this rectangle with the resulting sub-rectangles.
- When the optimization run starts, create an empty region handled by the above customized code, call this the `master region`
- Iterate through the `blt` queue, and for every entry:

  - Let `srcrect` be the source rectangle for the `blt` beng examined
  - Get the intersection of `srcrect` and `master region` into `temp region`
  - Remove `temp region` from `master region`, so `master region` no longer covers `temp region`
  - Promote `srcrect` to a region (`srcrgn`) and subtract `temp region` from it
  - Offset `temp region` and `srcrgn` with the vector of the current `blt`: their union will cover the destination area of the current `blt`
  - Add to `master region` all rects in `temp region`, retaining the original source metadata (step one of adding the current `blt` to the `master region`)
  - Add to `master region` all rects in `srcrgn`, adding the source information for the current `blt` (step two of adding the current `blt` to the `master region`)
- Optimize `master region` by checking if adjacent sub-rectangles that are merge candidates have the same metadata. Two sub-rectangles are merge candidates if `(r1.x1 == r2.x1 && r1.x2 == r2.x2) | (r1.y1 == r2.y1 && r1.y2 == r2.y2)`. If yes, combine them.
- Enumerate `master region`'s sub-rectangles. Every rectangle returned is an optimized blt operation destination. The associated metadata is the blt operation`s source.

Answer (score 2):

One idea that comes to mind is to store the defining points of the rectangles that are being added in a quad-tree (or in some other structure that will enable efficient collision detection). So now when you add a new rectangle, you can test it for collisions. The idea is that when a new rectangle collides with an old rectangle, you resolve the collisions by breaking the old rectangle into 4, 3, or 2 new rectangles that do not include the portion that intersects the newly added rectangle. We know that the old rectangle didn't intersect any other old rectangles and so, because the newly created ones are contained in it, we know that they don't intersect any either so you don't have to perform collision detection on them.

For example, starting with:

[image]

and adding one rectangle:

[image]

would resolve to:

[image]

Here, one of the old rectangles gets broken into two new rectangles and the other gets broken into three.

This guarantees that after a new rectangle is added, the queue is always in a state with no intersections which means that copying those rectangles will not copy a pixel twice.

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest in this. However, I think you may not have read the question carefully enough. (Or maybe I wasn't clear enough, do you think I should clarify?) What you describe is essentially what an efficient region handling library / API does. I am actually planning on relying on one. The real issue is that all these rectangles move to a certain position on the screen. Rect1 will move to X1,Y1 and Rect2 will move to X2, Y2, etc. What I'm trying to do is detect any overlaps in the ordered move operations themselves, and only move an overlapping block once.

Comment: The problem is that Rect1 moves first, then Rect2 moves, etc. They don't all move at the same time. If Rect2's source overlaps with Rect1's destination, it will copy some of its bits. Likewise, Rect3's source may overlap with Rect1's and Rect2's destination, etc.

Comment: @martona I see the problem. I'm not really a graphics guy so I misunderstood. I think I see a solution but I'll have to wait until later tonight to update.

Comment: Your answer attempt inspired me nonetheless. Check out my edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

SDL_BlitPool.. ah that my early work.

BlitPool's way is

```
for_each(down to up) {
 if (overlapped) {
  1 split back-surface
   1-1 calculate overlap code
   1-2 add sub-rectangle (use overlap code)
   1-3 delete divided-surface
 }
}
```

basicly that's all.

"overlap code" is 0-15 integer.

you know, overlap-pattern is just 16 pattern.

http://bitbucket.org/sharow/sdl_blitpool/src/ea6c02fef26f/resource/SDL_BlitPool_02.png

Overlap code is 4bit(0-15) value.

First 2bit is Y-axis and tail 2bit is X-axis(in SDL_BlitPool).

Each 1bit value is just MSB value.

It visualize like...

http://bitbucket.org/sharow/sdl_blitpool/src/ea6c02fef26f/resource/SDL_BlitPool_01.png

in this image: MSB == arrow-direction.

I thought that there was better library for another.
hmm I want rewrite it...

sorry for my level of English.